# Overlap container hide header row on resize - fix height width of some container

Tags: resize, containers, javafx-8

I am having fxml, which have top row where all my update / delete / save buttons resides. Beneath it I am having one TreeTableView where my data display.

Problem is when I am resing my window from top to bottom my header row disappear/missing/not showing/hidden/ovelap. I am finding the solution where from certain widht/height user cannot resize the window and whatever component is essential those can be visible after resize from anywhere.

Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections ?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem?>

<VBox prefHeight="780.0" prefWidth="1120.0" stylesheets="@../Cls.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
    <AnchorPane id="topAnchopane">
            <children>

                                <HBox fillHeight="false" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="400.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="3.0" StackPane.alignment="TOP_RIGHT">
                    <children>                      
                        <Button fx:id="tmpl_reset" minHeight="16.0" minWidth="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onResetColumnConfig" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="16.0" text="">
                                                                    <cursor>
                                                                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                                    </cursor>
                     <styleClass>
                        <String fx:value="icon" />
                        <String fx:value="clear" />
                     </styleClass>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" top="4.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                                                                </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="tmpl_clear" minHeight="16.0" minWidth="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClearTemplate" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="16.0" text="">
                                                                    <cursor>
                                                                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                                    </cursor>
                     <styleClass>
                        <String fx:value="icon" />
                        <String fx:value="reset" />
                     </styleClass>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" top="4.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                                                                </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="tmpl_delete" minHeight="16.0" minWidth="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onDeleteTemplate" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="16.0" text="">
                                                                    <cursor>
                                                                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                                    </cursor>
                     <styleClass>
                        <String fx:value="icon" />
                        <String fx:value="delete" />
                     </styleClass>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" top="4.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                                                                </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="tmpl_save" minHeight="16.0" minWidth="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onSaveTemplate" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="16.0" text="">
                                                                    <cursor>
                                                                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                                    </cursor>
                     <styleClass>
                        <String fx:value="icon" />
                        <String fx:value="save" />
                     </styleClass>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" top="4.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                                                                </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="tmpl_search" minHeight="16.0" minWidth="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#advancedSearch" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="16.0" text="">
                                                                    <cursor>
                                                                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                                    </cursor>
                     <styleClass>
                        <String fx:value="icon" />
                        <String fx:value="search" />
                     </styleClass>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" top="4.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                                                                </Button>                                       
                        </children>
                </HBox>
                <HBox fillHeight="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="980.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="140.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="3.0" StackPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT">
                    <children>
                        <HBox prefHeight="24.0">
                           <children>
                              <Text text="Template Name">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="10.0" top="7.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin></Text>
                              <ComboBox fx:id="templateNameComboBox" promptText="Select Template Name">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="5.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin></ComboBox>
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox prefHeight="24.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label styleClass="seperator" text="">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin></Label>
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox prefHeight="24.0">
                           <children>
                               <Text text="Template Type ">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets top="7.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin></Text>
                               <Label fx:id="templateTypeComboBox">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin></Label>
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox prefHeight="24.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label styleClass="seperator" text="">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin></Label>
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox prefHeight="24.0">
                           <children>
                              <CheckBox fx:id="defaultTemplate" disable="true">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets top="4.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin></CheckBox>
                            <Text text="Default Template">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets top="7.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin></Text>
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <HBox prefWidth="850.0">
            <children>
                <AnchorPane minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="484.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>


                        <TreeTableView fx:id="treeTableView" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="1.0" minHeight="400.0" minWidth="754.0" prefHeight="752.0" prefWidth="754.0" styleClass="k-table-view" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="43.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <columns>
                                <TreeTableColumn style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Message Type">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <TreeItemPropertyValueFactory property="messageType" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TreeTableColumn>


                                <TreeTableColumn prefWidth="110.0" style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="MessageId">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <TreeItemPropertyValueFactory property="messageId" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TreeTableColumn>

                                <TreeTableColumn prefWidth="115.0" style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Originator Reference">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <TreeItemPropertyValueFactory property="originatorRef" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TreeTableColumn>

                                <TreeTableColumn prefWidth="115.0" style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Search Key">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <TreeItemPropertyValueFactory property="searchKey" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TreeTableColumn>

                                <TreeTableColumn style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Message Description">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <TreeItemPropertyValueFactory property="guiMessageStatusDesc" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TreeTableColumn>

                                <TreeTableColumn style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Message Reason">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <TreeItemPropertyValueFactory property="guiMessageStatus" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TreeTableColumn>

                                <TreeTableColumn prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Updated Date Time">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <TreeItemPropertyValueFactory property="updateTime" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TreeTableColumn>

                                <TreeTableColumn prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="XML Link">
                                    <cellValueFactory>
                                        <TreeItemPropertyValueFactory property="xmlMessage" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TreeTableColumn>
                            </columns>
                            <columnResizePolicy>
                                <TreeTableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                            </columnResizePolicy>
                        </TreeTableView>
                        <HBox layoutX="2.0" layoutY="745.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="474.0">
                            <children>
                                <Label text="Page Count">
                                    <HBox.margin>
                                        <Insets top="17.0" />
                                    </HBox.margin>
                                </Label>
                                <TextField fx:id="itemsPerPage" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="50">
                                    <HBox.margin>
                                        <Insets left="8.0" top="14.0" />
                                    </HBox.margin>
                                </TextField>
                                <Pagination fx:id="pagination" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="235.0" translateX="1.0" translateY="1.0">
                                    <HBox.margin>
                                        <Insets top="8.0" />
                                    </HBox.margin>
                                </Pagination>
                                <Label fx:id="displayInfo">
                                    <HBox.margin>
                                        <Insets top="17.0" />
                                    </HBox.margin>
                                </Label>
                            </children>
                        </HBox>

                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </children>
    <styleClass>
        <!-- <String fx:value="Sapphire" /> -->
        <String fx:value="defaultFont" />
    </styleClass>
</VBox>
```

These are the images before and after

**Before Resize:**
[image: Before Resizing]
**After Resize**
[image: AfterResize]

Comment: There are many layouts in the code. Please give them an id and describe your problem which layout[id] is overlapping (hiding) with which layout[id].

Comment: First anchorpane where ID is id="topAnchopane". It is hiding when resizing from top.

Comment: I can see it on window resize, though it is flickering while resing. Tested with 1.8_40 on Ubuntu.

Comment: What do you have in Cls.css?

Comment: For this ID? Nothing. I just created it. I dont have any css rules for this anchor pane.

Comment: Can you post an image before and after the resize.

Comment: Question updated @Uluk Biy

Comment: Well I am not on Windows so cannot tell anything for it. But on Ubuntu it is working. By the way I could see the top-right red button in the code.

Comment: If I am resizing from top or bottom. It goes disappear. Is there any properties to define it or need to act in .css?

Comment: I think no but test by not importing the css file and try again. In my previous comment I actually was saying "By the way I could **NOT** see the top-right red button in the code."

Comment: Ya you cannot see that button due to it will come from other controller and bind to every fxml which I have working. I think you can forget that button.

Comment: To have exactly the same environment both code in question and the problem you are facing, try to create a fresh fxml app in IDE and copy the code in the question. If the problem is not occurring there, then you need to provide more detail of your real code.

Comment: Let me try it. Thank you.